# Show images on login form in Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a login page using forms authentication method.
I have inserted a image in login page but image is not visible in Browser.As it is viewed in design view in Visual Studio.

I think there is a issue in accessing image directory by anonymous user.I have used the following code in Web.config

```
<location path="/images">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users ="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: what do you see when you right click and see the image detail on your web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it. I have added Web.cofig with following code in images and css folder to give them anonymous access.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```